# How many times faster is SSHD compared with HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I was recently briefed to [SSHD drives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive#SSHD) in the sense they can provide near-SSD beyond-HDD speed for data storage and retrieval. How many times faster is really than an ordinary 7200 rpm HDD drive?

Comment: I have a few of these at work and for 99% of the time they are no faster than a spinner although it could be that my usage pattern (as a software developer) does not let the USB stick drive cache work effectively. BTW, I call it USB stick cache instead of SSD because the drive uses a single flash chip instead of multiple flash chips in raid0 that a ssd uses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much faster is SSD compared to regular hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/802530/how-much-faster-is-ssd-compared-to-regular-hard-drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres impossible to give you an answer on "How many times faster" because there is no answer to this, it will depend on many factors.

A hybrid hard drive will be significantly faster than a mechanical drive. That caching algorithm will store operating system and program files in the solid-state memory, offering solid-state speeds when accessing cached files.

For benchmark comparison you can visit this site: http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/WD-VelociRaptor-1TB-vs-Seagate-Desktop-SSHD-1TB/1389vs1784